# is possible to make a button shape like a cross?

Tags: android-studio

is possible to have a single button that has a shape of a cross and that it is clickable only in the visible part?

defining curves with coordinates or setting an image with this cross and somehow setting that where the image is transparent, it must not be clickable ..
if yes, with witch method?

I tried to search online but apart from the radus (which in this case I don't need), I didn't find any documentation

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add your button as ImageButton and put your shap in that button

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_close_image"/>
```

Comment: if it's helpful for you please upvote and accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: this simply put the image on the object, if i click on trasparent area, the onlickevent starts